# Calculating Beamer presentation progress excluding appendix

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, appendices, pgfmath

### Problem description

In trying to calculate the progress of a Beamer presentation, one can use

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{100*(\insertpagenumber)/(\insertdocumentendpage)}
```

where `\prog` tracks the percentage value of the progress.

To take into account that a presentation may possibly contain an appendix, and to exclude slides therein from the calculation of `\prog`, I naturally thought that one can simply change `\insertdocumentendpage` to `\insertpresentationendpage`, or `\insertappendixstartpage-1` when an appendix does exist. However, doing so results in an error:

> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `=' or `=4' (in '100*(3)/({\beamer@tempcount =4\relax 0})').

If `\insertappendixendpage` is used, there is no error (but the value of `\prog` will be wrong).

The following MWE contains no appendix, so the four `\insert<...>`s should have the same value. However, uncommenting either of the last two frames results in the abovementioned error.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{100*(\insertpagenumber)/(\insertdocumentendpage)}
    progress = \prog
}

\frame{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{100*(\insertpagenumber)/(\insertappendixendpage)} 
    progress = \prog
}

% \frame{
%     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{100*(\insertpagenumber)/(\insertappendixstartpage-1)} 
%     progress = \prog
% }

% \frame{
%     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{100*(\insertpagenumber)/(\insertpresentationendpage)} 
%     progress = \prog
% }

\end{document}
```

### Question

Why is this the case, and how can I correct it?

---

### Edit (based on [Tom Bombadil](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7279/tom-bombadil)'s long comment)

Try adding this outside of a frame:

```
\typeout{======================================}
\show\insertdocumentendpage
\typeout{======================================}
\show\insertpresentationendpage
\typeout{======================================}
\show\insertappendixstartpage
\typeout{======================================}
```

The equal signs are just there so it's easier to find in the *.log* file. This will return

```
======================================
> \insertdocumentendpage=\long macro:
->\beamer@endpageofdocument .
l.27 \show\insertdocumentendpage
======================================
> \insertpresentationendpage=\long macro:
->{\ifx \beamer@startpageofappendix \@empty \beamer@tempcount =\beamer@endpageo
fdocument \relax \else \beamer@prevpage \beamer@startpageofappendix \relax \fi
\the \beamer@tempcount }.
l.29 \show\insertpresentationendpage
======================================
> \insertappendixstartpage=\long macro:
->{\ifx \beamer@startpageofappendix \@empty \beamer@tempcount =\beamer@endpageo
fdocument \relax \else \beamer@tempcount =\beamer@startpageofappendix \relax \f
i \the \beamer@tempcount }.
l.31 \show\insertappendixstartpage
======================================
```

Apparently, the problem is related to the fact that `\insertdocumentendpage` just returns a value, while `\insertpresentationendpage` and `\insertappendixstartpage` return an expression that needs to be evaluated first. So the question can be refined to either

- How can one force `\pgfmathparse` to evaluate this first? or
- How can one save the result of such an expression in a macro?

Comment: That's weired indeed. `\xdef\x{\insertappendixstartpage}  \x` returns a number as expected, but a `\pgfmathsetmacro{\prog}{\x}` afterwards fails in the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also write your own macros for these and `beamer` code is really strange. However, as the name implies these should not be expected to be easy numbers since the numbers are inserted hence warning for nonexpansion.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\makeatletter
\gdef\appendixstartpageno{%
\ifx\beamer@startpageofappendix\@empty%
  \beamer@endpageofdocument%
\else%
  \beamer@startpageofappendix%
\fi%
}
\gdef\presentationendpageno{%
\ifx\beamer@startpageofappendix\@empty%
  \beamer@endpageofdocument%
\else%
  \number\numexpr\appendixstartpageno-1\relax%
\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,17}{
\begin{frame}{Frame \x: Progress \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{round(100*(\insertpagenumber/\presentationendpageno))}\prog \%}
    Dummy frame \x
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{round(100*(\insertpagenumber/\presentationendpageno))}

    \tikz{\fill[blue!20](0,0) rectangle ({(\prog/100)*1cm},5mm) node[below right] {\prog \%};
          \draw(0,0) rectangle (1cm,5mm);
        }
\end{frame}
}


\appendix
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
\begin{frame}{Frame \x}
    Dummy appendix frame \x 
\end{frame}
}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

With appendix, you can use the TeX count `\beamer@startpageofappendix`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\insertprogress{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prog}{100*(\insertpagenumber)/(\beamer@startpageofappendix - 1)}
  \prog
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame{progress = \insertprogress}
\frame{progress = \insertprogress}
\frame{before appendix; progress = \insertprogress}
\appendix
\frame{Appendix A}
\frame{Appendix B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [appendixnumberbeamer](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendixnumberbeamer) package from CTAN, it automatically excludes the slides in the appendix from numbering/progress bar