# Beamer / TIKZ / PGF: Using a Variable (Math / Calculations) as Part of a File Name for an External File

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, calculations

I want to indicate the progress of a `beamer` presentation using external pictures.

> Let's say we are at slide 24 out of 200 slides then I want to display
>   a picture called `12.png` (24/200 = 12 %) on the current slide.

I am already able to manage to calculate the percentage of the progress **but I can't use \pgfmathresult** (`\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}`, which in my MWE gives the progress percentage of the current slide) **as part of a file name** (error `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`).

I use the `calc` library of `tikz/pgf` to do the calculations.

In the MWE I input an external `tex` file in order to emulate inserting a picture.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{33.tex}
File with name \texttt{33.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{67.tex}
File with name \texttt{67.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{100.tex}
File with name \texttt{100.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

%% Start of Frame
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
%
\begin{description}
\item[Current Frame Number] \insertframenumber
\item[Total Frame Number] \inserttotalframenumber
\item[Progress in Percent] 
    \pgfmathparse{min((100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber),100)} 
    \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}\,\%
\end{description}
%
\input{33.tex}
\end{frame}

%% Start of Frame
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
%
\begin{description}
\item[Current Frame Number] \insertframenumber
\item[Total Frame Number] \inserttotalframenumber
\item[Progress in Percent] 
    \pgfmathparse{min((100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber),100)} 
    \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}\,\%
\end{description}
%
\input{67.tex}
\end{frame}

%% Start of Frame
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
%
\begin{description}
\item[Current Frame Number] \insertframenumber
\item[Total Frame Number] \inserttotalframenumber
\item[Progress in Percent] 
    \pgfmathparse{min((100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber),100)} 
    \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}\,\%
\end{description}
%
\input{100.tex}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

> When you first compile the document then `\inserttotalframenumber` is
>   1 (One). So if you are on slide 3 (Three) then the current progress percentage is 300 (slide 3 out of 1). Therefore I use the `min` function to restrict the result of the
>   calculation to be 100 at maximum.

---

**Related**

- [Calculating Beamer presentation progress excluding appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141157)
- [Progress bar for latex-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742)

Comment: Are you sticking to `pgfmath...` calculations?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer **I do not.** I just thought that pgf/tikz will be modern (state of the art) and easy to use.

Comment: `\pgfmathresult` does not survive the group, that's the point

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok. As I said - I do not need to use pgfmath. Thanks for the help by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exploits `expl3` features of easy calculation and storing values into a property list, the `\prop_item:Nn` command is expandable, whereas the expansion content of `\pgfmathresult` does not survive the `description` environment group, it will show `0.0` most likely.

The wrapper command `\retrievepercentage` is expandable as well then and can be used as argument to `\input` in order to generate the corresponding filename.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{33.tex}
File with name \texttt{33.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{67.tex}
File with name \texttt{67.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{100.tex}
File with name \texttt{100.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_beamer_percentage_int
\prop_new:N \g_beamer_percentage_prop
\NewDocumentCommand{\getpercentage}{}{%
  \int_set:Nn  \l_beamer_percentage_int {\fp_to_int:n {\fp_eval:n { min((100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber),100)}}}
  \prop_gput:NnV \g_beamer_percentage_prop {percentage} { \l_beamer_percentage_int }
}

\newcommand{\retrievepercentage}{%
  \prop_item:Nn \g_beamer_percentage_prop {percentage}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

%% Start of Frame
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
%
\begin{description}
\item[Current Frame Number] \insertframenumber
\item[Total Frame Number] \inserttotalframenumber
\item[Progress in Percent]
  \getpercentage%
  \retrievepercentage
\end{description}
%

\input{\retrievepercentage.tex}
\end{frame}

%% Start of Frame
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
%
\begin{description}
\item[Current Frame Number] \insertframenumber
\item[Total Frame Number] \inserttotalframenumber
\item[Progress in Percent] 
  \getpercentage%
  \retrievepercentage
\end{description}
%
\input{\retrievepercentage.tex}
\end{frame}

%% Start of Frame
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
%
\begin{description}
\item[Current Frame Number] \insertframenumber
\item[Total Frame Number] \inserttotalframenumber
\item[Progress in Percent] 
  \getpercentage%
  \retrievepercentage
\end{description}
\input{\retrievepercentage.tex}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Details of the solution.

As explained above, `\pgfmathresult` will not keep the result being stored in the `description` environment since this is TeX group.

A possible bypass would use an `\xdef` - based approach, say `\xdef\foo{\pgfmathresult}` which is a globally expanded definition, i.e. `\foo` will contain the value of `\pgfmathresult` at definition time.

I tried another strategy to calculate the result of the percentage with `expl3` (the upcoming (;-)) LaTeX 3 format)

Let's look into the code...

```
\int_new:N \l_beamer_percentage_int
```

defines a new integer 'variable' (internally it is a TeX count register)

```
\prop_new:N \g_beamer_percentage_prop
```

defines a property list, which is something like `expl3`'s version of a hash-table or array, i.e. key names can be defined and a value assigned to it.

```
  \fp_to_int:n {\fp_eval:n {min((100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber),100)}}
```

evaluates (`\fp_eval:n`) the floating point (fp) expression with `min(...)` which looks equal basically to the `pgfmath` approach.
After evaluation it is converted ('truncated') to an integer value, which is stored to the `\l_beamer_percentage_int` with `\int_set:Nn`.

The set-operation is not expandable, it can not be used in expansion chains, e.g. like in the generation of the filenames as requested here, but storing the value to property list is a possible way with

```
  \prop_gput:NnV \g_beamer_percentage_prop {percentage} { \l_beamer_percentage_int }
```

this means: Globally put (gput) the Value (V) of `\l_beamer_percentage_int` into the list named `\g_beamer_percentage_prop` and assign it to key `percentage`.

Finally, calling the command `\prop_item:Nn \g_beamer_percentage_prop {percentage}` is the slower but expandable version of getting the stored value.

I refer to the description of `texdoc interface3` for the details about the name conventions used in `expl3`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a resource hint where I can read about stuff like **\prop** and so on? It would be perfect if the solution also would work with **\beamer@startpageofappendix** (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141157).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner https://texdoc.net/pkg/interface3

Comment: Better to use `xparse` to make a protected outer layer than using `\newcommand` :)

Comment: It works perfectly. Can you elaborate the code a little bit? It all looks very unfamiliar to me :).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Great! **a)** So this only works for integers now? (which is fine). **b)** Is the tikz package needed anymore or are the calculations done using the calc package features?

Comment: Is it possible to include the **\getpercentage** in the **\retrievepercentage**? So I just have to use one command in the frames? I tried to put **\getpercentage** in the **\retrievepercentage** definition but it didn't work (no output).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: No, not this way. You would overwrite the property value each time you're using `retrievepercentage` because `\getpercentage` recalculates the value again -- the values of the input for computing the percentage are lost outside however

Comment: Hmmm - I tried it again and I thought it worked (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347560). Now I have another problem, but this problem (question here) is solved.

Comment: I'm not sure why using a property list instead of a token list.

Comment: @egreg: That's possible too, of course. I thought of extending and storing other values later on, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an expandable command:

```
\begin{filecontents}{33.tex}
File with name \texttt{33.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{67.tex}
File with name \texttt{67.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{100.tex}
File with name \texttt{100.tex}.
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\percentageofpresentation}{}
 {
  \fp_to_int:n { 100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%% Start of Frame
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
%
\begin{description}
\item[Current Frame Number] \insertframenumber
\item[Total Frame Number] \inserttotalframenumber
\item[Progress in Percent] \percentageofpresentation
\end{description}
%
\InputIfFileExists{\percentageofpresentation.tex}{}{NOT YET COMPUTED}
\end{frame}

%% Start of Frame
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
%
\begin{description}
\item[Current Frame Number] \insertframenumber
\item[Total Frame Number] \inserttotalframenumber
\item[Progress in Percent] \percentageofpresentation
\end{description}
%
\InputIfFileExists{\percentageofpresentation.tex}{}{NOT YET COMPUTED}
\end{frame}

%% Start of Frame
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
%
\begin{description}
\item[Current Frame Number] \insertframenumber
\item[Total Frame Number] \inserttotalframenumber
\item[Progress in Percent] \percentageofpresentation
\end{description}
%
\InputIfFileExists{\percentageofpresentation.tex}{}{NOT YET COMPUTED}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With `\InputIfFileExists` we cope with the problem of the first LaTeX run. In your project you can do

```
\IfFileExists{\percentageofpresentation.png}
  {\includegraphics{\percentageofpresentation.png}}
  {NOT YET COMPUTED}
```