# expl3/xparse: Having an **if check** in a command

Tags: beamer, expl3

Maybe the question is not minimal enough - if so, please tell me.

> I do not know what is the correct title since I do not understand
>   the connection of the different packages.

### Related

This question is somehow a follow up of

- [Beamer / TIKZ / PGF: Using a Variable (Math / Calculations) as Part of a File Name for an External File](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347121/)

and also includes

- [Calculating Beamer presentation progress excluding appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141157).

### Introduction

The basic idea is, that I calculate the progress (in percent) of a `beamer` presentation using

```
100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
```

I added a `min(progress in percent,100)` around that all because in the first run the `\inserttotalframenumber` is `1` and I do not want the progress to exceed 100.

> At the moment I do not know which LaTeX package is responsible that I
>   can use the `min` function here.

So it actually looks like

```
min((100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber),100)
```

This fails if there is an appendix because I do not want that the appendix slides to be taken into account.

If there is an appendix then this approach

```
min((100*\insertframenumber/(\beamer@startpageofappendix-1))
```

works. The key is `\beamer@startpageofappendix`. But it fails if there is no appendix because then `\beamer@startpageofappendix-1` is `-1` (minus one).

### Main Question

> I thought that it would help if there was a check if
>   **`\beamer@startpageofappendix` is zero** in the code. Depending on the result, approach a) (`\inserttotalframenumber`) or b)
>   (`\beamer@startpageofappendix-1`) will be used.

### Code

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \int_new:N \l_beamer_percentage_int
    \prop_new:N \g_beamer_percentage_prop
    \makeatletter
    \NewDocumentCommand{\myProgressPercent}{}{%
    \int_set:Nn  \l_beamer_percentage_int {
        \fp_to_int:n {
            \fp_eval:n {min((100*\insertframenumber/(\beamer@startpageofappendix-1)),100)}
            %\fp_eval:n {min((100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber),100)}
            }
        } 
    \prop_gput:NnV \g_beamer_percentage_prop {percentage} { \l_beamer_percentage_int }
    \prop_item:Nn \g_beamer_percentage_prop {percentage}
    }
    \makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,10}{
%------------------
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Slide \n}
    Progress is \myProgressPercent\,\%
\end{frame}
%------------------
}

%  comment \appendix in and out to see the effect
\appendix

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
%------------------
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Appendix Slide \n}
    Progress is \myProgressPercent\,\% (Should always be 100\,\%)
\end{frame}
%------------------
}

\end{document}
```

### It wokred!

Thanks all - here's illustration of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the need of using that indirection: the command can be even made fully expandable:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\myProgressPercent}{}
 {
  \fp_to_int:n
   {
    min(
     100*\insertframenumber
     /
     (
      \use:c{beamer@startpageofappendix} - 1 > 0
      ?
      \use:c{beamer@startpageofappendix} - 1
      :
      \inserttotalframenumber
     )
     ,
     100
    )
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,10}{
%------------------
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Slide \n}
    Progress is \myProgressPercent\,\%
\end{frame}
%------------------
}

%  comment \appendix in and out to see the effect
\appendix

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
%------------------
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Appendix Slide \n}
    Progress is \myProgressPercent\,\% (Should always be 100\,\%)
\end{frame}
%------------------
}

\end{document}
```

We check whether `\beamer@startpageofappendix` is set to some number (greater than one, of course) and, in this case we use it (less one). Otherwise we use `\inserttotalframenumber`.

Note that, for your intended application, you can even say

```
\includegraphics{\myProgressPercent.png}
```

because `\myProgressPercent` will just expand to a number.

Comment: Works like a charme. I wanted to use **\myProgressPercent** in **tikz** picture as an variable/option. Your solution works whereas the solution I used in my question did not work - brilliant!

Comment: You could use the ternary operator instead of `\fp_compare`.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_beamer_percentage_int
\prop_new:N \g_beamer_percentage_prop

\NewDocumentCommand \myProgressPercent { }
  {
    \int_set:Nn  \l_beamer_percentage_int
      {
        \fp_to_int:n
          {
            \tl_if_empty:cTF { beamer@startpageofappendix }
              {
                \fp_eval:n
                  {
                    min(100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber,100)
                  }
              }
              {
                \fp_eval:n
                  {
                    min(100*\insertframenumber/(\use:c {beamer@startpageofappendix}-1),100)
                  }
              }
         }
      }

    \prop_gput:NnV \g_beamer_percentage_prop {percentage} { \l_beamer_percentage_int }
    \prop_item:Nn \g_beamer_percentage_prop {percentage}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,10}{
  % ------------------
  \begin{frame}{Slide \n}
    Progress is \myProgressPercent\,\%
  \end{frame}
  % ------------------
}

%  comment \appendix in and out to see the effect
%\appendix

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
  % ------------------
  \begin{frame}{Appendix Slide \n}
    Progress is \myProgressPercent\,\% (Should always be 100\,\%)
  \end{frame}
  % ------------------
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A little simplified version.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \myProgressPercent { }
  {
    \tl_if_empty:cTF { beamer@startpageofappendix }
      {
        \fp_to_int:n
          {
            min(100*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber,100)
          }
      }   
      {
        \fp_to_int:n
          {
            min(100*\insertframenumber/(\use:c {beamer@startpageofappendix}-1),100)
          }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,10}{
  % ------------------
  \begin{frame}{Slide \n}
    Progress is \myProgressPercent\,\%
  \end{frame}
  % ------------------
}

%  comment \appendix in and out to see the effect
%\appendix

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
  % ------------------
  \begin{frame}{Appendix Slide \n}
    Progress is \myProgressPercent\,\% (Should always be 100\,\%)
  \end{frame}
  % ------------------
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are a genius :). Stupid me - I stuck in thinking about a **if else construct**. Very elegant solution - loving it. But wait - i get wrong percentages...I have to check.

Comment: Still - now I get only negative and wrong values.

Comment: Please remove the **\appendix** command to check. It works for me too if I have an appendix but it doesn't work (wrong percentage) if I do not have an appendix.

Comment: Both answers are great - I tossed a coin! Is that ok for you?