# beamer: Determine the Last Frame Before Appendix Starts (Even if There Are <Overlay Specifications>)

Tags: beamer, expl3

- Normally I have something like **Frame 4 / 30** in the `footline`.
- The total frame count is done by the command `\insertframenumber`.
- In my beamer presentation, I have an extensive appendix/backup.
- Therefore I didn't want the appendix frames to be counted to the total frame count.
- I used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141157/) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347560) question to do that -- leading to a new custom command called `\myLastContentFrame`.
- Everything was good.
- Now I used `overlay specification`s like `[<+->]` and the `\myLastContentFrame` sadly also considers the overlays into account.

> How to determine the last frame before the appendix even if overlay
>   specifications are used? In the appendix frames I want e. g. **34 / 30** (where 30 is the last content frame count).

[image]

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}

%% Appearance
% -----------------------
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=pink}
% -----------------------

%% Functionality
% -----------------------
\usepackage{xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347560
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\myLastContentFrame}{}
 {
  \fp_to_int:n
   {
     (
      \use:c{beamer@startpageofappendix} - 1 > 0
      ?
      \use:c{beamer@startpageofappendix} - 1 
      :
      \inserttotalframenumber
     )
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% -----------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Content Frame 1}
\begin{itemize}
\huge
\item \texttt{\textbackslash insertframenumber:} \insertframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash inserttotalframenumber:} \inserttotalframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame:} \myLastContentFrame
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Content Frame 1}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\huge
\item \texttt{\textbackslash insertframenumber:} \insertframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash inserttotalframenumber:} \inserttotalframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame:} \myLastContentFrame
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Last Content Frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\huge
\item \texttt{\textbackslash insertframenumber:} \insertframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash inserttotalframenumber:} \inserttotalframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame:} \myLastContentFrame
\end{itemize}

\begin{block}{Last Content Frame}
The number of this frame -- the last frame befpore the appendix starts -- should be the value of \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame}.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Appendix Frame}
\Huge \textcolor{red}{Start of Appendix!}
\begin{itemize}
\huge
\item \texttt{\textbackslash insertframenumber:} \insertframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash inserttotalframenumber:} \inserttotalframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame:} \myLastContentFrame
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you could save the total frame number much easier.

Comment: Why are you torturing us with such background colours?

Comment: @samcarter This time I tried something new...I'll do better/different next time :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Keine Drohungen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might suspend the counter `framenumber` with the command `\SuspendCounters` from the `xassoccnt` package, i.e.

with `\SuspendCounters{framenumber}`.

If the counting should be reenabled, say `\ResumeSuspendedCounters{framenumber}` later on.

I also changed to using total counters, i.e. with `\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters` (requires `xassoccnt` v1.2)

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

% Pre version 1.1 of xassoccnt version
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalframenumbers}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{framenumber}{totalframenumbers}

% Version 1.2. of xassoccnt allows this in one go...
%\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{framenumber}{totalframenumbers}

%% Appearance
% -----------------------
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=pink}
% -----------------------

%% Functionality
% -----------------------
\usepackage{xparse}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347560

\newcommand{\myReallyLastContentFrame}{%
  \TotalValue{totalframenumbers}
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\myLastContentFrame}{}
 {
  \fp_to_int:n
   {
     (
      \use:c{beamer@startpageofappendix} - 1 > 0
      ?
      \use:c{beamer@startpageofappendix} - 1 
      :
      \inserttotalframenumber
     )
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% -----------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Content Frame 1}
\begin{itemize}
\huge
\item \texttt{\textbackslash insertframenumber:} \insertframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash inserttotalframenumber:} \inserttotalframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame:} \myReallyLastContentFrame 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Content Frame 1}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\huge
\item \texttt{\textbackslash insertframenumber:} \insertframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash inserttotalframenumber:} \inserttotalframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame:} \myReallyLastContentFrame
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Last Content Frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\huge
\item \texttt{\textbackslash insertframenumber:} \insertframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash inserttotalframenumber:} \inserttotalframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame:} \myReallyLastContentFrame
\end{itemize}

\begin{block}{Last Content Frame}
The number of this frame -- the last frame befpore the appendix starts -- should be the value of \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame}.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\appendix

\SuspendCounters{framenumber}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Appendix Frame}
\Huge \textcolor{red}{Start of Appendix!}
\begin{itemize}
\huge
\item \texttt{\textbackslash insertframenumber:} \insertframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash inserttotalframenumber:} \inserttotalframenumber
\item \texttt{\textbackslash myLastContentFrame:} \myReallyLastContentFrame
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fresh idea. I'll try it tomorrow. Is the idea that there is a new counter that synchronizes with the beamer counter?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Yes, that's the basic purpose of the `xassoccnt` packages. The total document counter feature is used in order to store the counter value at the end of the document to the `.aux` file and reuse it with the next run.

Comment: I just tested the code. It compiles well. Apparently I was unclear about my objective: I still want that the `framenumber` counter counts on so that in the appendix I have e. g. frame 34/30. So every frame still has an individual frame number to which I can refer to.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I can change my solution but actually, I can't follow the strategy behind your numbering scheme

Answer (score 5):

No need to reinvent the wheel, `appendixnumberbeamer` already did this for you:

(the only thing I changed is to comment two lines from the original appendix definition, otherwise the appendix would restart counting from 1)

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber}

\makeatletter
\def\appendix{
  \xdef\mainend{\theframenumber}
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\global\string\@namedef{mainendframenumber}{\mainend}}
  \appendixorig
%  \gdef\inserttotalframenumber{\appendixtotalframenumber}%
%  \setcounter{framenumber}{0}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\pause[3]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}
Appendix
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what the general approach is?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The general approach is to use a package which does what you want :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner For "more" information `texdoc appendixnumberbeamer`

Comment: Haha - ok...I meant why do "we" need the stuff between `\makeatletter`and `\makeatother`. If it seems to be a silly question -- I really don't know.

Comment: Seriously: I'll test it tomorrow.  Good night :). (btw: I still want that the normal frame counter goes beyond the total frame counter -- like frame 34/30 if 30 is the last content frame and 34 is a frame in the appendix). I can't test it right now because I updated MiKTeX and it went wrong...

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner As said in my answer, the "stuff" between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is necessary to make make your frame counter to go beyond the total framenumber. Normally it would restart with 1

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Perfect time to switch to texlive :)

Comment: Ahhhh - I was blind somehow.

Comment: @samcarter: A package that uses `\makeatletter...\makeatother`? Oh my ... But as I can see, it uses a similar approach to `totcount`, but it is no package at all, in the sense of `\ProvidesPackage`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unnecessary, but it does not hurt, does it?

Comment: @samcarter: According to egreg `\makeatletter` should **never** appear in a package...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But what will happen to a mere mortal package writer who did this? Will he be bound to a mountain and an eagle is picking out all @ from his liver? Or will he only be excluded from the pantheon of TeX-Gods?

Comment: @samcarter: `\let\eagle\egreg` ;-) ... No, he will never be allowed to write packages again or upload something to the Holy Shrine of Typography (i.e. CTAN );-)

Comment: @egreg You are an eagle now :). And sadly, it took me some seconds until I got the joke.

Comment: I accept the other answer -- **I literally flipped a coin**. Both solve the problem/question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I hope the coin had an egreg - errr - eagle on one side :)